# How to use server-side processing in JQuery DataTables without Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, datatables

I'm using [JQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net) with Vue 2. The below snippet shows how I'm using it with a JSON data source **fetched from a custom method** using the [`wretch`](https://github.com/elbywan/wretch) package (it also handles authorization).

```
...
mounted: function () {
  this.dataTable = window.$(this.$el).DataTable({
    data: this.getGridData,
    columns: this.getColumns,
    // serverSide: true
  });
},
...
```

This method is working fine. Now I want to enable the `serverSide` feature to control `pagination` and `search` without using the `ajax` option.

My backend application is running in .NET Framework. I have created my response data structure as shown [here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/object_data.html), but it doesn't seem to help.

Simply, I want to use my **custom method** to fetch data into the DataTable while using the `serverSide` feature.

Is this possible? I'm looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataTables has various different forms for its [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option.

One of these is as follows:

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
    // whatever logic you want to use can go here,
    // as long as it evaluates to a valid JSON structure
    // expected by DataTables, as a server-side response.
    callback(
        resultsOfYourLogic  
    );
  }
} );
```

You can read its description in the linked documentation - but it basically states:

> *As a function, making the Ajax call is left up to yourself allowing complete control of the Ajax request. Indeed, if desired, a method other than Ajax could be used to obtain the required data...*

Therefore, you can use this - with `serverSide: true` - to use any alternative method you wish to source your data.

Example:

```js
"ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
  var dataSet = yourCustomFunction(data);
  callback(
    dataSet 
  );
},
```

Here, the custom function is invoked first, returning the JSON which needs to be displayed. The request data is passed to that custom function. Then the results of that custom function are placed in the callback.

One important note here is: The `data` parameter in the callback will be pre-populated with the [server-side request](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) data (automatically created by DataTables whenever the user sorts/filters/pages). So you will need to handle this request data, to know how your response data needs to be built.

(The response data structure you link to in your question, is the correct structure.)

Comment: Awesome! Perfect solution. Thank you.